# jQuery dynamic width/height are not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery segment where I'm trying to dynamically set the width and height of some div elements based on the width and height of the div they're in:

```
numBlocks = 256;
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 0;
    maxArea = $("#container").width() * $("#container").height();
    squareSideLength = Math.sqrt(maxArea / numBlocks);
    $(".square").css("width", squareSideLength);
    $(".square").css("height", squareSideLength);

    while(i < numBlocks)
    {
        $("#container").append("<div class='square'></div>");
        i++;
    }
});
```

I know that the squareSideLength is getting calculated correctly, but the width and height of the .square class is not being set correctly. After the .squares are added, the width and height are showing up as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
$(".square").css("width", squareSideLength);
$(".square").css("height", squareSideLength);
```

don't apply prospectively, to elements created after they get run.

You can use that same strategy except set the width and height *after* you add all the `.square` elements (or directly on each element as you insert it into the loop).

If you can have non-dynamic dimensions that don't need to be calculated in JavaScript, it would obviously be easier to just set styles for `.square` in static CSS.

Comment: This was exactly it! Moved those lines below the while loop and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property after the creation of elements not before

Test here : https://jsfiddle.net/aa4moxks/

```
numBlocks = 256;
$(document).ready(function () {
    i = 0;
    maxArea = $("#container").width() * $("#container").height();
    squareSideLength = Math.sqrt(maxArea / numBlocks);

    while(i < numBlocks)
    {
        $("#container").append("<div class='square'></div>");
        i++;
    }

    $(".square").css("width", squareSideLength);
    $(".square").css("height", squareSideLength);
});
```